# Elasticsearch filter for site with count of goods for filter fields

Tags: elasticsearch

It is necessary to implement the filter, as in the picture (to derive all possible values ​​and the number of products found for each query). Example:

[filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NieDi.png)

I have a list of parameters for which you need to filter (Diagonal, Price, Matrix Type, etc.) and documents in Elasticsearch, and somehow, you need to get the result as in the picture.

The simplest way is to find the unique values ​​distinct (for the diagonal, find 11 ", 12.9", 15.9 ") for each property, and then for each possible value to count the number of found goods (count) .But this method is a ton of queries and all this will have to be cached.

Is there a way to get the desired result with one query?